# How to assign current-date in WSO2 BPEL?

Tags: datetime, wso2, xquery, bpel

I didn't found way how to assign current-date in WSO2 BPEL.
I tried this:

[$ode:currentEventDateTime](http://ode.apache.org/extensions/xpath-extensions.html)

```
<bpel:from expressionLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">
<![CDATA[$ode:currentEventDateTime]]>
</bpel:from>
```

It raises error:

> [UndeclaredVariable] Attempt to reference undeclared variable "currentEventDateTime" while deploying

[fn:current-dateTime or current-dateTime()](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_current-datetime.html)

```
<bpel:from expressionLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">
<![CDATA[fn:current-dateTime]]>
</bpel:from>
```

> Fault Name    {http: //docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}selectionFailure
>   Fault Message     {http: //docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}selectionFailure: R-Value expression "{OXPath10Expression fn:current-dateTime}" did not select any nodes.
>   Fault Data    No data available.

```
<bpel:from expressionLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">
<![CDATA[fn:current-dateTime()]]>
</bpel:from>
```

raises:

> ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.ui.fileupload.BPELUploadExecutor} -  BPEL Process Compilation Failure.
>   org.apache.ode.utils.NSContext$NSContextException: Namespace not found for prefix "fn" while deploying.

```
<bpel:from expressionLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">
<![CDATA[current-dateTime()]]>
</bpel:from>
```

> Fault Name    {http: //docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}selectionFailure
>   Fault Message   {http: //docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}selectionFailure: An exception occured while evaluating "{OXPath10Expression current-dateTime()}": No Such Function current-dateTime
>   Fault Data  No data available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution by using xsl transformation
BPEL:

```
<bpel:copy> 
<bpel:from>bpel:doXslTransform("datetime.xsl", $variable.part)</bpel:from>
<bpel:to part="parameters" variable="var"></bpel:to>
</bpel:copy>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<!--variable structure--> 
<cmism:deliveryDate><xsl:value-of select="current-dateTime()"/>
</cmism:deliveryDate>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```